# Time complexity analysis of function with recursion inside loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to analysis time complexity of below function. This function is used to check if a string is made of other strings.

```
set<string> s; // s has been initialized and stores all the strings
bool fun(string word) {
    int len = word.size();

    // something else that can also return true or false with O(1) complexity

    for (int i=1; i<=len; ++i) {
       string prefix = word.substr(0,i);
       string suffix = word.substr(i);
       if (prefix in s && fun(suffix))
           return true;
       else
           return false;
    }
}
```

I think the time complexity is `O(n)` where n is the length of word (am I right?). But as the recursion is inside the loop, I don't know how to prove it.

Edit:

This code is not a correct `C++` code (e.g., `prefix in s`). I just show the idea of this function, and want to know how to analysis its time complexity

Comment: I doubt that it's `O(n)`.  The outer loop executes `n` times, and each one calls the function again.  I'm thinking something bad, like `O(2^n)`.  And could you explain what you mean by a string being made of other strings?

Comment: @Teepeemm like word1 = abcdef, word2 = abc, word3 = def. word1 is made of word2 and word3

Comment: This code looks buggy. Shouldn't the loop start at `i=1`? As it is, unless `s` contains the empty string, this will always return `false` immediately, and if `s` does contain the empty string, it will recurse infintely. Also, unless `s` is initialized with something, `prefix in s` will always evaluate to `false`. That would also make the function return `false` immediately.

Comment: @TedHopp Yes, this code is not correct. I just want to show the idea of this function and decide its complexity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to analyze this is by developing a recursion relationship based on the length of the input and the (unknown) probability that a prefix is in `s`. Let's assume that the probability of a prefix being in `s` is given by some function pr(L) of the length L of the prefix. Let the complexity (number of operations) be given by T(len).

If len == 0 (`word` is the empty string), then T = 1. (The function is missing a final `return` statement after the loop, but we're assuming that the actual code is only a sketch of the idea, not what's actually executing).

For each loop iteration, denote the loop body complexity by T(len; i). If the prefix is not in `s`, then the body has constant complexity (T(len; i) = 1). This event has probability 1 - pr(i).

If the prefix is in `s`, then the function returns `true` or `false` according to the recursive call to `fun(suffix)`, which has complexity T(len - i). This event has probability pr(i).

So for each value of `i`, the loop body complexity is:

> T(len; i) = 1 * (1 - pr(i)) + T(len - i) * pr(i)

Finally (and this depends on the intended logic, not the posted code), we have

> T(len) = sum <sub>i=1...len</sub>(T(len; i))

For simplicity, let's treat pr(i) as a constant function with value 0.5. Then the recursive relationship for T(len) is (up to a constant factor, which is unimportant for O() calculations):

> T(len) = sum <sub>i=1...len</sub>(1 + T(len - i)) = len + sum <sub>i=0...len-1</sub>(T(i))

As noted above, the boundary condition is T(0) = 1. This can be solved by standard recursive function methods. Let's look at the first few terms:

```
len   T(len)
0     1
1     1 + 1 = 2
2     2 + 2 + 1 = 5
3     3 + (4 + 2 + 1) = 11
4     4 + (11 + 5 + 2 + 1) = 23
5     5 + (23 + 11 + 5 + 2 + 1) = 47
```

The pattern is clearly T(len) = 2 * T(len - 1) + 1. This corresponds to exponential complexity:

> T(n) = O(2<sup>n</sup>)

Of course, this result depends on the assumption we made about pr(i). (For instance, if pr(i) = 0 for all i, then T(n) = O(1). There would also be non-exponential growth if pr(i) had a maximum prefix length—pr(i) = 0 for all i > M for some M.) The assumption that pr(i) is independent of i is probably unrealistic, but this really depends on how `s` is populated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've fixed the bugs others have noted, then the `i` values are the places that the string is being split (each `i` is the leftmost splitpoint, and then you recurse on everything to the right of `i`).  This means that if you were to unwind the recursion, you are looking at up to `n-1` different split points, and asking if each substring is a valid word.  Things are ok if the beginning of `word` doesn't have a lot of elements from your set, since then you can skip the recursion.  But in the worst case, `prefix in s` is always true, and you try every possible subset of the `n-1` split points.  This gives `2^{n-1}` different splitting sets, multiplied by the length of each such set.

Comment: could you explain why it is 2^{n-1} different splitting in the worst case? THX!

Comment: As things stand, the loop executes with `i=1` and then returns.  This means that `fun` is `O(n)` in the worst case.  Assuming that the loop should execute with all `i` and then return, it may be easier to think of a subset.  Then this subset corresponds to `i=subset[0]`, with the rest of the subset depending on the recursion on `suffix`.